# tensorflow decoded jpg image error, but cv2 is right

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I used two methods to decode one jpeg image file, one is tensorflow(abbreviated to tf), the other is opencv(abbreviated to cv2). But cv2 is right and tf got some errors. The code is as following:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2

path = 'one jpeg file path'

img_tf = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.io.read_file(path))

img_cv2 = cv2.imread(path)
```

img_cv2 got right, but img_tf got errors:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-e44ad973b8b3> in <module>
----> 1 img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(tf.io.read_file(path))

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_image_ops.py in decode_jpeg(contents, channels, ratio, fancy_upscaling, try_recover_truncated, acceptable_fraction, dct_method, name)
   1176             try_recover_truncated=try_recover_truncated,
   1177             acceptable_fraction=acceptable_fraction, dct_method=dct_method,
-> 1178             name=name, ctx=_ctx)
   1179       except _core._SymbolicException:
   1180         pass  # Add nodes to the TensorFlow graph.

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_image_ops.py in decode_jpeg_eager_fallback(contents, channels, ratio, fancy_upscaling, try_recover_truncated, acceptable_fraction, dct_method, name, ctx)
   1259   "acceptable_fraction", acceptable_fraction, "dct_method", dct_method)
   1260   _result = _execute.execute(b"DecodeJpeg", 1, inputs=_inputs_flat,
-> 1261                              attrs=_attrs, ctx=_ctx, name=name)
   1262   _execute.record_gradient(
   1263       "DecodeJpeg", _inputs_flat, _attrs, _result, name)

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     65     else:
     66       message = e.message
---> 67     six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
     68   except TypeError as e:
     69     if any(ops._is_keras_symbolic_tensor(x) for x in inputs):

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError: Expected image (JPEG, PNG, or GIF), got unknown format starting with 'II*\000\226%\026\000\177wgjvo_r' [Op:DecodeJpeg]
```

Some people know something about this, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the file you are providing is actually in JPEG format? According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) `II*` is signature of TIFF file (the extension of your file might be wrong).

Could you try another JPEG image?

You are not getting error with OpenCV since it can read TIFF images, while `tf.io.decode_jpeg` can not.

Comment: Thanks very much. Great help to me.

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark the answer as correct, if it solves your problem.